# Getting Time out error and run time error in test case 2 and 3 in hackerrank. How to resolve this?

Tags: python-2.7

The objective of this code is to print sum of multiples of 3 and 5 between given range. In hackerrank, I am getting error in test case 2 and 3. Anyone knows how to resolve the issue?

```
t =int(raw_input())  
for i in range(0,t):
range = int(raw_input())
a=3
b=5
aa=[]
res=[]
def forA(a):  #Calculating Multiple of 3
    while True:
        if a >=range :
            a = a-3
            break
        else:
            aa.append(a)
            a += 3;

def forB(b):  #Calculating Multiple of 5
    while True:
        if b >=range :
            b=b-5
            return b
            break
        else:
            aa.append(b)
            b += 5;


forA(a)
forB(b) 
for i in aa:    #eliminate duplicate values of multiples. 
    if i not in res:  
        res.append(i)

print sum(res)
```

Comment: To consider having an idea I would have to create and account for / log into hackerrank, find this puzzle, get the testcases and analyze what you did. Sorry, not going to bother. Maybe you could provide more information regarding these test cases so we could try to solve it without all the hassle? Time out probably means youre not doing somtheing fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

This might resolve your problems because it uses pythons builtin features that are "smart" instead of creating a list one item a time yourself. Therefore they are faster... which might solve the timing errors you get.

You get all the numbers up to your input from 3 or 5 till t by

```
from itertools import chain
t =15

threes = range(0,t+1,3) # range provides [lower..higher[ not including higher value
fives = range(0,t+1,5)

sums = sum(chain(threes,fives)) # without itertools: sums=sum(threes) + sum(fives)
print(threes)
print(fives)
print(sums)
```

If you want to avoid multiples, avoid `chain(..)`, uses sets and join them together before summing them up

```
s = set(threes) | set(fives)

print(sum(s))
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15] # threes up to 15
[0, 5, 10, 15] # fives up to 15
75 # sum of chained ones
60 # sum of set
```

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick. code ran fine. sorry I didn't provided any test cases. The issue was with timing. your code ran faster and passed all the test cases.  Thanks very much.